# Bash language is incorrect

Tags: bash, macports, language

I'm using Bash 5.1.8 from MacPorts as my shell. For some reason Bash is part French and I can't figure out why. Launching Terminal.app with "Set locale environment variables on startup" checked, I get this output from various commands:

```
$ locale
LANG="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_CA.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

$ printf '%(%A %d %B %Y)T\n'
Saturday 13 November 2021

$ asdf
-bash: asdf : commande introuvable

$ help printf
printf: printf [-v var] format [arguments]
    Formate et affiche des ARGUMENTS en contrôlant le FORMAT.
    
    Options :
      -v var    affecte la sortie à la variable VAR du shell plutôt que de l'afficher
            sur la sortie standard
    
...
```

All internal Bash messages are showing as French, but when internal Bash commands use system libraries to generate output they get the right locale (as in `printf` above which is a Bash builtin but uses the `strftime` library to output.) Unchecking the above box in Terminal preferences reverts locale to the default "C" but gives the same behaviour.

System locale info looks like this:
[image: screenshot of language and region preferences]

How can I get the right language set?

Comment: Anything set on the Apps tab?

Comment: No, it’s empty.

Comment: There is a [post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337244/homebrew-and-git-wrong-language-on-the-command-line) with similar problem in Mojave.

Comment: Could you try setting `LANG=en_CA`? It seems that the information for the `en_CA.UTF-8` locale is missing: is there a folder named `en_CA.UTF-8` in the MacPorts folder hierarchy (it is most probably located in `<MacPorts base directory>/share/locale/`)?

Comment: @PtitXav yeah I think that's it; [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/360156/54556) is the key. MacPorts is on the same old version of the `gettext` lib. There's an open bug from 2.5 year ago to upgrade, hopefully it happens soon.